# Bluetooth devices disconnect but still show as connected (17.10)

Tags: bluetooth, 17.10

I upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 yesterday, and since then all of my bluetooth devices randomly drop connection. They are still listed as connected on the bluetooth app (I believe it is the default program) but nothing gets sent to or from them and the devices themselves say they are disconnected. The time they stay connected could be for 3 hours, or it could be 3 minutes

I have changed the IdleTimeout setting in /etc/bluetooth/input.conf to be 0 but that didn't help.

Anybody had this problem since upgrading and managed to fix it? It seems that most solutions to similar problems have mixed results and often only work temporarily. Interestingly though, other people with similar issues often have the same laptop as mine - the Lenovo Thinkpad T460s...

Thanks

Comment: setting`IdleTimeout=30` in `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf` seems to have fixed issues for me for now on Ubuntu 17.10. But I agree its too buggy.

Comment: Thanks, tried that and it seems to improve a little, but every now and then it still drops. It seems to be something to do with WiFi as when that is turned off, it doesn't seem to drop the BT at all.

Comment: I'm having the same issue